# mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I freshly created a new meteor (1.2.1) project like this (on a Debian 7.7) but I'm not able to enter the mongo terminal:

```
$ meteor create test
$ cd test
$ meteor run
[[[[[ ~/test ]]]]]                           

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

and in a new terminal:

```
$ meteor mongo
mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.

This command only works while Meteor is running your application locally.         
Start your application first with 'meteor' and then run this
command in a new terminal. This error will also occur if you asked Meteor to
use a different MongoDB server with $MONGO_URL when you ran your
application.

If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed with 
'meteor deploy', specify your site's name as an argument to this
command.
```

Yes it is running a local MongoDB server!!
What's wrong here, what shall I do?
`$MONGO_URL` is empty btw. mongodb is installed, though, but not used (only need mongodump and mongorestore to connect to meteor's mongo).

Thanks

Comment: Those 4 commands above, did you run them all sequentially in one terminal session?   i.e., did you stop the `meteor run` command (e.g. `Cmd-C`) before running `meteor mongo`?  If so this doesn't work, as at that point meteor is not running.  You need to run `meteor mongo` in a new terminal while `meteor run` is still executing.  
Otherwise, check what `echo $MONGO_URL` shows.

Comment: Yes I startet a new terminal while meteor run, sorry that was unclear.

Comment: $MONGO_URL is empty btw

Comment: in the new terminal, are you in the project directory?

Comment: jep i'm in the project dir

Comment: Try creating the example todo app (because it uses the db out of the box) and see if the app runs correctly:   `meteor create --example todos`

Comment: app runs fine with db out of the box, as you said, but `meteor mongo` doesn't :(

Comment: `Works for me!` Sorry, not sure what's going on.  See if you can replicate the issue elsewhere (i.e. spin up cheap vps)

Answer (score 2):

Got this error running windows 10.
Funny thing is, `meteor mongo` was working before then all of a sudden it didn't work. I don't quite remember what i did but it could have been closing the terminal with the window close icon instead of ctrl+c.

Anyway what i did was run:

```
>meteor mongo localhost:3001
```

this output the following error

> Sorry, Meteor does not yet support specific path URLs, such as
>   http://www.example.com/blog .  Please specify the root of a domain

And then I run the `>meteor mongo` command again and boom!! it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it turned out that it works when I don't use the cloud9 IDE terminal but connect directly. So eventually it was a ENV / terminal problem? I have no idea. But it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I ran meteor on port 80. To do that Ubuntu required root permissions to use the port. I then got the same error when running meteor mongo as a regular user.

To fix I just used sudo and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you are using `CTRL+c` for the same terminal in which meteor is running. This will close the meteor and you will not be able to connect with mongo.

Answer (score 0):

The author said his/her `$MONGO_URL` is empty but whoever has `$MONGO_URL`

You may want to make sure if there is `$MONGO_URL` on your `zshrc` or whatever you use.

I removed `$MONGO_URL` and run `echo $MONGO_URL` on the terminal and it worked.