# Meteor error - Storing tasks in a collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I am following the meteor site tutorial (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections).

But when you add the line:

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

I get the following error:

```html
/Users/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.fpzmec++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
      throw(ex);
      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at Object.Future.wait (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.fpzmec++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:216:27)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:103:40)
    at meteorInstall.imports.api.tasks.js (imports/api/tasks.js:4:14)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
    at Module.Mp.import (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.6_1.j54juu++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
    - - - - -
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.1.5.50.1g0yl8n++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:169:7)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.1.5.50.1g0yl8n++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:260:12)
    at [object Object].g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.1.5.50.1g0yl8n++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:162:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Which port are you using ? I can see 27017

Answer (score 0):

The line in the tutorial:

```
export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

Is different from your line:

```
Export Tasks const = new Mongo.Collection ('tasks');
```

The goal of the code is to initialize a new constant, `Tasks`, set it to a new `Mongo.Collection`, and then export it.

Comment: Is Mongo imported in the file?

Comment: Yes, import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Comment: That is a bit strange. What happens if you run `meteor mongo` from the console? (From the same directory as your meteor app, while it is running)

Comment: mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.

This command only works while Meteor is running your application locally. Start your application first with 'meteor' and then run this command in a
new terminal. This error will also occur if you asked Meteor to use a different MongoDB server with $MONGO_URL when you ran your application.

If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed with 'meteor deploy', specify your site's name as an argument to this command.

Comment: Ok, so it is not connecting to Mongo. It could be a sudo / permissions issue, or something else. I would take a look at these threads to continue:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853700/cant-connect-to-local-running-mongo-using-meteor-mongo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638548/mongo-meteor-isnt-running-a-local-mongodb-server

Comment: It is a setting of the environment variable $MONGO_URL. But I do not know what to do = /

Comment: The most likely culprit is that you don't have sufficient directory permissions for Mongo, so it is failing to connect. In that case you would want to `sudo chown` the directory. But it could be other things as well. As for the MONGO_URL, what does it say when you run console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL) from any server-side code in your Meteor app? Most likely that is not the issue if you are running a fresh project install from the tutorial, but it is worth taking a look. It looks like it is correct from the MongoError thrown in your question.